# Is there a dashboard widget for displaying (and monitoring or reloading) plain text files?

Tags: dashboard, widgets

I use todo.txt as a todo list manager, and so my todo list is saved as a text file. I'd like for there to be a widget that monitors text files, so that it's not on my desktop, but in my dashboard. Is there a widget for this?

Also, I can't seem to figure out how to search for widgets in http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/?r=dbw without looking through all the categories. Bug?

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick you can use to do this without using any other sort of dashboard widget:

This [MacTipper](http://www.mactipper.com/2008/08/three-uses-for-open-in-dashboard.html) article from 2008 shows how if you open a text file in Safari, you can then send that file to be opened in Dashboard.

> ... anything you can open in Safari, you can have on the dashboard. This includes text (TXT) files. If you combine this with other fun things you can do with text files, **such as your basic todo list**, you can put some pretty good information on the dashboard. As with images, you just need to open the text file in Safari and add it to the Dashboard.

Apple have removed that ability in later version of Safari, however using a simple HTML file allows you to bypass that restriction as in the example below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>TODO List</title>
</head>
<body> 
  <iframe src="todo.txt" width="600" height="400">    
</body>
</html>
```

For other people who come to this thread looking to get TODO lists in the Dashboard, then iSlayer's [Organized](http://islayer.com/apps/organized/) is a Dashboard widget that provides TODO functionality in the Dashboard.

> To do’s are synced with OS X’s built-in database, so Organized will
>   always reflect what’s shown in Mail and other apps.

Comment: Safari's "open in dashboard" command doesn't work with .txt files--the menu item is grayed-out.

Comment: Obviously taken out by Apple for some reason, I've posted a work-around that I came up with above if you want to try that.